# How to use AtomicCell::compare_exchange to update only a particular field of Struct

Tags: rust

I have a requirement wherein an `f64` data gets updated every 10ms in a thread and every 1s the `f64` data needs to be printed only if it's updated, in a separate thread. To get this functionality I made use of `AtomicCell<Struct>` from `crossbeam` crate. The problem that I'm facing is how to apply `compare_exchange` on this `AtomicCell<Struct>` where in only the `bool` field `is_updated` should be reset to `false` if its `true` and also get the actual `f64` data if `true`. This is my attempted code

```
use crossbeam::atomic::AtomicCell;

#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone)]
struct AnglePosition {
    is_updated: bool,
    angle: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let angle_pos = AtomicCell::new(AnglePosition {
        is_updated: true,
        angle: 56.789,
    });
    
    // want to use AtomicCell::compare_exchange wherein only is_updated should be set to false but angle value should remain the same in this case 56.789
    // below operation is not fully atomic because it's performing two separate atomic operations
    let updated_angle_pos = angle_pos.load();
    if updated_angle_pos.is_updated {
        angle_pos.store(AnglePosition {
            is_updated: false,
            angle: updated_angle_pos.angle,
        });
        println!("angle position data updated");
    }
    
    let updated_angle_pos = angle_pos.load();
    if !updated_angle_pos.is_updated {
        println!("angle position data not updated after last read");
    }
}
```

Please note I can't use `AtomicF64` crate as I also have one more requirement wherein I just need to read the `f64` data that's present inside `AtomicCell` struct irrespective of `is_updated` value.

Comment: [The type is not lock-free](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8b7050964ddc051b978dad1bc94859c), so it has no advantage over using a mutex, which will also solve your problem.

Comment: if it's not lock-free, then it will make use of Mutex internally right? https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/atomic/struct.AtomicCell.html#

Comment: Yes, it will. Which means just storing `Mutex` directly will be more efficient.

Comment: `compare_exchange` does nothing for you here, since `AnglePosition` is too big. If you really wanted to be lock free for some obscure reason, you would use an atomic cas in a loop on a separate "is_in_critical_section" field, and only read or write the data if you managed to set that flag to true. But then you're just re-implementing locking, so just use `Mutex`